# How to Negate a Pattern Test and Transform a List of Strings to a JSON array

Tags: pattern-matching

First I would like to find out how to negate a pattern and based on this I would like to solve this little problem on how to transform a list of strings to a JSON array. This is how I started working on the problem.

```
listEmptyQ[lst_List]:=Length[lst]==0

listToX[lst_List?listEmptyQ]:="[]"

listToX[lst_List /; Not[listEmptyQ[lst]]]:="["<>ToString[lst]<>"]"

listToX[{a, b}]
(* [{a, b}] *)

listToX[{}]
(* [] *)
```

So, I would like to avoid the constraint operator (/;) on the non-empty list case and turn this to a pattern test instead.

And is there a built-in predicate for testing an empty list ?

Comment: If you define `listToX[{}] := "[]"` first before the general case, then you don't need to worry about negations.

Comment: Any reason not to write such a thing as `listToX2[lst_List] := 
 "[" <> StringReplace[ToString@lst, "{}" -> ""] <> "]"`?

Comment: To answer your first question, in version 10, `listToX[lst_List?(Not@*listEmptyQ)] := ...`. In earlier versions `listToX[lst_List?(Composition[Not, listEmptyQ])] := ...`. Or `listToX[lst_List?(Not@listEmptyQ@# &)] := ...`

Comment: Or `listToX[lst : Except[_List?listEmptyQ]] := ...`

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. You are right, but I wanted also to know the answer to my question for a general purpose.

Comment: @SimonRochester Thank you so much, this is great, why don't you build an answer based on the reply of your comment and get the credit ? Otherwise I will do it for you ;-)

Comment: @ciao, it is just an example to learn the answer ;-)

Comment: @Athanassios: Ah, got it. Lots of pattern experts here, and good info in the tutorial/wiki entries here (just go to top rated questions, several of the top ones are such things). You will find mastering the pattern/transformation system of Mathematica most satisfying!

Comment: @ciao, thank you for your suggestion. Mathematica Exchange is a great community of users with excellent content. I really enjoy learning WL day by day ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I am answering the question in an interesting, thorough way for the reader based on the useful comments I had from other community members. I believe this example is excellent for demonstrating many pattern oriented features inside function definitions. Let me know what you think.

**Predicate Definition**

```
listEmptyQ[lst_List] := Length[lst] == 0
```

**Testing List**

```
testList = {{}, {"first", "second", "third"}};
```

*The following function, defined in **FIVE** different ways, converts a list of strings to a json array. In this case, please also note that I have made the pattern more specific using BlankNullSequence of Strings*

1.**Without using the predicate listEmptyQ**

The base case is defined first, so we do not need to define the predicate

```
listToX[{}] := "[]"
listToX[lst:{__String}] :="[" <> StringDrop[StringJoin@(("\"" <> # <> "\",") & /@ lst), -1] <> "]"

listToX /@ testList
(* {[],["first","second","third"]} *)
```

2.**Pattern Test by Negating Predicate listEmptyQ**

```
listToZ[lst:{__String}?listEmptyQ] := "[]"

listToZ[lst:{__String}?(Not@*listEmptyQ)] := "[" <> SringDrop[StringJoin@(("\"" <> # <> "\",") & /@ lst), -1] <> "]"

listToZ /@ testList
(* {[],["first","second","third"]} *)
```

3.**Negate Constraint**

```
listToY[lst:{__String} /; listEmptyQ[lst]] := "[]"
listToY[lst:{__String} /; Not[listEmptyQ[lst]]] :=  "[" <> StringDrop[StringJoin@(("\"" <> # <> "\",") & /@ lst), -1] <> "]"

listToY /@ testList
(* {[],["first","second","third"]} *)
```

4.**Pattern Test Using Except**

```
listToW[lst:{__String}?listEmptyQ] := "[]"
listToW[lst:Except[{__String}?listEmptyQ]] := "[" <> StringDrop[StringJoin@(("\"" <> # <> "\",") & /@ lst), -1] <> "]"

listToW /@ testList
(* {[],["first","second","third"]} *)
```

5.**Using If**

```
listToS[lst:{___String}]:= If[Length[lst] == 0, "[]","[" <> StringDrop[StringJoin@(("\"" <> # <> "\",") & /@ lst), -1] <> "]"]

listToS /@ testList
(* {[],["first","second","third"]} *)
```

Comment: Alternatively: `listEmptyQ[l_] := l === {}`.

Comment: Or perhaps, `listEmptyQ[{ }] = True; listEmptyQ[{__}] = False;`

Comment: What I think about this is that it is much ado about very little.

Comment: +1 Unrelated to "negating a pattern test", but incidentally it is unnecessary to check `listEmptyQ` for the pattern `{__String}` (two underscores) since it will only match non-empty lists.  The pattern `{___String}` (three underscores) will match both empty and non-empty lists.

Comment: @WReach, you are right. I feel great to share my learning experience with the experts (that is to answer @m_goldberg). Working on this example I find that it makes a huge difference narrowing the pattern. In this specific transformation from a list of strings to a JSON array it becomes clear that the use of the listEmptyQ predicate is unnecessary, (see 5.). What is necessary is to define the base case on the recursive kind of StringJoin pure Function. Therefore I believe that the most elegant solutions are 1. and 5.

Comment: Perhaps it is a good idea to write something general about restrictions on Patterns. For example, highlight the main difference between headed, sequence patterns (i.e. arbitrary symbolic structures) and applying Condition or PatternTest. It seems to me the first defines the domain, i.e. set of expressions and the second permits to focus on subsets. Is there such a generic post on this, or bring together material from other relative posts ?